# Senki Zesshou Symphogear season 1: Does anyone know the name of the track that plays at 23:46 during episode 12?

Tags: music, senki-zesshou-symphogear

Senki Zesshou Symphogear season 1: Does anyone know the name of the track that plays at 23:46 during episode 12?

It plays just after the classmates sing over the PA near the end of S1 ep 12; the track starts playing when Hibiki realizes she can still fight due to Miku's song healing.

It has a very 80's techno vibe and it leads directly into the ending song "Synchrogazer" for the ep 12 credits.

Any insight would be appreciated, I've been going through the OST for all 3 seasons without luck. The amount of character music for the show is impressive, but it also makes it rather difficult to find a non-vocalized track.

Answer (score 2):

Boy oh boy do I have a treat for you, my good fellow! The track you're describing is actually a long-intro remix of "Synchrogazer", titled "Synchrogazer -⁠Aufwachen Form⁠-".

It's no surprise that you had trouble finding it - this remix doesn't actually appear on any of the *Symphogear* soundtracks! Rather, it's part of Mizuki Nana's album ["Rockbound Neighbors"](http://vgmdb.net/album/36371). Similarly, her album ["Supernal Liberty"](http://vgmdb.net/album/44417) comes with another glorious remix titled "Vitalization -⁠Aufwachen Form⁠-". That's the version that plays in episode 13 of G when they all follow the Nephilim into the Treasury.

(Alas, I don't think either "Exterminate" or "Glorious Break" have analogous remixes.)